# Pthread segment fault using pointer to variable in main

Tags: c++, pthreads

I'm new to pthread and attempting to implement a producer/consumer problem that will let the user pick buffer size, # of producers, # of consumers, and total # of items. I've been looking through what I thought were similar things on stack overflow, but can't seem to get it right.

My code has a main class and it spawns producers and consumers. It hands the producers and consumers a pointer to a stack initialized in main (or at least I'm trying to). I thought that what I was doing was legal and in CLion I get the predictive text options I want so I thought I linked it properly but I'm segfaulting when I try to read the top element.

I used GDB to make sure I knew what line I was crashing on, but don't understand what's wrong with my setup. While debugging I confirmed that a producer goes through its push() command first, but the consumer fails when attempting top() or pop(). I'd seen some threads here where the OP had problems because they didn't join their threads, but I am so I'm a little lost.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stack>
#include <cstring>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define N 10000

sem_t mutex;
sem_t fullCount;
sem_t emptyCount;
int iCount = 0;

typedef struct _thread_data{
    int id;
    int itemcount;
    std::stack<char>* ptr;
}thread_data;

void *producer(void *arg){
    std::cout << "spawned producer\n";
    thread_data *data = (thread_data *)arg;
    while(true){
        char message = 'X';
        sem_wait(&emptyCount);
        sem_wait(&mutex);
        if(iCount < data->itemcount){
            data->ptr->push(message);
            iCount++;
            char temp [25];
            sprintf(temp, "p:<%u>, item: %c, at %d\n", data->id, message, data->ptr->size());
            std::cout << temp;
            //std::cout << "hi I'm a producer\n";
            sem_post(&mutex);
            sem_post(&fullCount);
        }
        else{
            sem_post(&fullCount);
            sem_post(&mutex);
            pthread_exit(nullptr);
        }
    }
}

void *consumer(void *arg){
    std::cout << ("spawned consumer\n");
    thread_data *data = (thread_data *)arg;
    while(true){
        char message;
        sem_wait(&fullCount);
        sem_wait(&mutex);
        if(iCount < data->itemcount) {
            message = data->ptr->top(); //SEGFAULT
            char temp[25];
            printf(temp, "c:<%u>, item: %c, at %d\n", data->id, message, data->ptr->size());
            data->ptr->pop();
            std::cout << temp;
            //std::cout << "Hi I'm a consumer\n";
            sem_post(&mutex);
            sem_post(&emptyCount);
        }
        else if (iCount == data->itemcount){
            message = data->ptr->top(); //SEGFAULT
            char temp[25];
            printf(temp, "c:<%u>, item: %c, at %d\n", data->id, message, data->ptr->size());
            data->ptr->pop();
            std::cout << temp;
            sem_post(&emptyCount);
            sem_post(&mutex);
            pthread_exit(nullptr);
        }
        else{
            sem_post(&mutex);
            pthread_exit(nullptr);
        }

    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int bufferSize = N;
    int pThreadCount,cThreadCount,itemCount;
    for (int x = 0; x < argc; ++x) {
        if(strcmp(argv[x],"-b") == 0){
            bufferSize = atoi(argv[x+1]);
        }
        if(strcmp(argv[x],"-p") == 0){
            pThreadCount = atoi(argv[x+1]);
        }
        if(strcmp(argv[x],"-c") == 0){
            cThreadCount = atoi(argv[x+1]);
        }
        if(strcmp(argv[x],"-i") == 0){
            itemCount = atoi(argv[x+1]);
        }
    }
    sem_init(&mutex,1,1);
    sem_init(&fullCount,1,0);
    sem_init(&emptyCount,1,bufferSize);

    std::stack<char> myStack;
    pthread_t myPThreads[pThreadCount];
    thread_data thrData[pThreadCount];
    pthread_t myCThreads[cThreadCount];
    thread_data cThrData[cThreadCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < pThreadCount; ++i) {
        thrData[i].id = i;
        thrData[i].itemcount = itemCount;
        thrData[i].ptr = &myStack;
        pthread_create(&myPThreads[i], NULL, producer, &thrData[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < cThreadCount; ++i) {
        cThrData[i].id = i;
        cThrData[i].itemcount = itemCount;
        thrData[i].ptr = &myStack;
        pthread_create(&myCThreads[i], NULL, consumer, &cThrData[i]);
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < pThreadCount; ++k) {
        pthread_join(myPThreads[k], NULL);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < cThreadCount; ++j) {
        pthread_join(myCThreads[j], NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `extern "C" int main` is not a valid C++, as well as `pthread_t myPThreads[pThreadCount];`

Comment: @VTT Thanks for the fast reply, I removed the `extern "C"` part, but I see `pthread_t someName[numberOfThreads]` in a bunch of examples, am I missing something?

Comment: Variable length array exist as (optional and uncommon) feature in recent C variants, but not in C++. If your compiler compiles this code then it is most likely a gnu extension.

Comment: @plshelp please update your code to reflect the current state of the things you have tried (removing extern "C" and anything else)

Comment: @VTT Is there a better way to implement the ability to input buffer size, number of producers, number of consumers, and total item count? When I remove the lines that try to reference myStack and just add print statements the threads seem to work ok.

Comment: @xaxxon Done, for just testing the ability to make threads I commented out the lines in producer and consumer that try to access myStack with the pointer and added the (now commented out) cout lines.

Answer (score 1):

`iCount <= data->itemcount` is always true. `consumer` never exits the loop. At some point, it exhausts the stack, and the subsequent `top()` call exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks for catching that with the loop, unfortunately the problem still persists. When stepping though to debug, the first producer goes through its code, then the first consumer seg faults at top() still.

Comment: `iCount == data->itemcount` clause may be entered multiple times (once by each consumer thread), which again may lead to calling `top` on empty stack.

Answer (score 0):

`cThrData[i].ptr` is never initialized, for any `i`. `consumer` calls `top()` through an uninitialized pointer, whereupon the program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20473048)

Comment: @Saveen Does too. `consumer` calls `top()` on an uninitialized pointer, hence the crash.